# sql - using result of query as input to another query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I got a DB with many tables, and I'm able to make a query that results in each record being the tables' names.

I created an example here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fa87b/3

Where what I need is another query that uses the existent one 'iterating' the name in result table.

What I want now is to query all the tables for one specific column.

Like for example:

```
SELECT column1 FROM (all tables which names are in a query result).
```

Comment: You need to generate the resulting queries as a string and use prepared statements.  You can't do this with a basic `select` query.

Comment: hi, can you exemplify using the example of the link ?

Comment: . . Start by reading the documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html).  Learn how to use prepared statements correctly, rather than through a basic example.

Comment: what you can do it to take query data into datatable and then iterate that query result one by one into your main query.. if you put some of your code may i will help you

Comment: @javardo as you use Oracle, is it ok to proceed with PL/SQL as it is purely Dynamic SQL.?

Comment: Hi amy, Im not using any programing language for that, just pure SQL